# Unbinding specific jquery elements

Tags: jquery, bind, unbind

Let's say I want to handle all links on a page, via a special function, so I do:

```
$('a').bind("click", handleLinks);
```

But I have a navbar with links that I want to handle differently. So I want to do this, which does not work:

```
$('#navbar a').unbind("click", handleLinks);
```

I do not want to specifically exclude the navbar in the first statement, because content is loaded dynamically, so the elements I need to monitor for clicks will change depending on the content. Basically I want to be able to unbind specific subsets of elements dynamically, from the larger initial subset of elements that was bound initially.

Any suggestions?

:: UPDATE ::

My sincere apologies, you're all correct - there was something funky with the order the commands were being called. Sorry!

Comment: I added some test code to my post as a demo
I'm doing pretty much the same thing and I'm not having a problem. Any chance you could post some surrounding code so we can try to troubleshoot it?

Comment: Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange- that looks correct. Have you tested that your initial statement is selecting what you think it does?

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/unbind

edit- 
Ok I did a test page

```
<body>
        <a href="#" class="a">Test A</a>
        <a href="#" class="a">Test A</a>
        <a href="#" class="a">Test A</a>
        <a href="#" class="b">Test B</a>
        <a href="#" class="a">Test A</a>
        <a href="#" class="b">Test B</a>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

                $(function(){

                    $('a').bind("click", testClick);
                    $('a.b').unbind("click", testClick);


                });

                function testClick(){
                    alert("Link Clicked");
                };
    </script>
    </body>
```

This works fine, however if I built my function inline I needed to unbind all events from select elements to remove it. Not sure if that applies or not but worth mentioning.

Do you mind posting a bit more code> it looks like there may be something else wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with apocalypse9 that it seems like what you have should work. Perhaps a different approach would have better results... How about using the :not selector with live(). Live will ensure the selector works with dynamically added elements.

```
$('a:not(#navbar a)').live("click", handleLinks);
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/not#selector

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live

Comment: "I do not want to specifically exclude the navbar in the first statement"

Comment: Thanks Scott, I edited the answer. Although it still may not work for him if the #navbar id is dynamic, which it sounds like it might be.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').not('#navbar a').bind('click', handleLinks);
```